# Dataloader on top of protobuf file using pytorch's torch.utils.data.IterableDataset

Tags: protocol-buffers, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a RNN network using pytorch.
The data is stored in various protobuf file.
Each record in protobuf represents one training example with multiple timestamp.

As this is very large dataset, reading the whole data in memory or random read by extending torch.utils.data.Dataset class isn't feasible.

As per the docs using the torch.utils.data.IterableDataset is recommended.

DataLoader on top of IterableDataset would be able to achieve parallelism

However I am not able to find an implementation of this on custom data,  docs only talk about a simple range iterator.

```
import math

import stream
from src import record_pb2
import torch

class MyIterableDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, pb_file):
        self.pb_file = pb_file
        self.start = 0
        self.end = 0
        # One time read of the data to get the total count of records in the dataset
        with stream.open(self.pb_file, 'rb') as data_stream:
            for _ in data_stream:
                self.end += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        worker_info = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()
        if worker_info is None:  # Single-process data loading, return the full iterator
            iter_start = self.start
            iter_end = self.end
        else:
            # in a worker process, split the workload
            per_worker = int(math.ceil((self.end - self.start))/float(worker_info.num_workers))
            worker_id = worker_info.id
            iter_start = self.start + worker_id * per_worker
            iter_end = min(iter_start + per_worker, self.end)

        data_stream = stream.open(self.pb_file, 'rb')

        # Block to skip the streaming data till the iter start for the current worker process
        i = 0
        for _ in data_stream:
            i += 1
            if i >= iter_start:
                break

        return iter(self.pb_stream)
```

I am expecting a mechanism by which a parallel data feeder could be designed on top of a large streaming data (protobuf)

Answer (score 0):

The `__iter__` method of the `IterableDataset` would `yield` your data samples one at a time. In a parallel setup, you have to choose the samples based on worker_id. And with respect to the `DataLoader` using this dataset, `shuffle` and `sampler` options would not work, as an `IterableDataset` is not going to have any indices. In other words, have your dataset yield one sample at a time and the data loader will take care of loading them. Does this answer?

Comment: scarecrow your response answers to an extent, but how do I achieve shuffling here ? I could only think of pre-fetching from generator and shuffling within the pre-fetched data before yielding a single example.

Comment: Yes that's an option. Another option would be to have mutiple files with proto records and have a mechanism to control the order in which these files are loaded/read.